# Magento 2.1:- Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Test\Plugin\Shipping ::afterCollectRates() for plugin issue

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, plugin

I create one plugin `Vendor\Test\Plugin\Shipping` for model `Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping.php` using di.xml

**app/code/Vendor/Test/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
    <plugin name="shipping_test" type="Vendor\Test\Plugin\Shipping" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Test/Plugin/Shipping.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Test\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
//use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Vendor\Test\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipment\Request;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Shipping
{

    protected $_code='Shipping';

    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    protected $_result;

    protected $_rateCollector;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Vendor\Test\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        RateCollectorInterface $rateCollector,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->_rateCollector = $rateCollector;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $group_info=$this->helper->getAllMethods();
        $carriers=array();
        foreach ($group_info as &$carrier) {
            $carriers[$group_info['label']]=$group_info['label'];
        }
        return $carriers;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $gid=$customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            $group_info=$this->helper->getGroupData($gid);
        }

        $err = null;
        $result = $this->_rateCollector->create()->collectRates($request)->get‌​Result();
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $method->setCarrier('Shipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle('sdtgd');
        $method->setMethod('Shipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle('dryfyu');
        $amount=0;

        return $result;
    }

}

?>
```

But i got the below error.
What is issue in this code ?

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\Test\Plugin\Shipping
::afterCollectRates() must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest, instance
 of Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/magento/m2/mage2
/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 152 and defined in /var/www/html/magento/m2/mage2/app/code/Vendor/Test/Plugin/Shipping.php:103
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/m2/mage2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(152
): Vendor\Test\Plugin\Shipping-&gt;afterCollectRates(Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping
\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor))
#1 /var/www/html/magento/m2/mage2/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor
.php(78): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor-&gt;___callPlugins('collectRates', Array, Array
)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/m2/mage2/vendor/magento/modul in <b>/var/www/html/magento/m2/mage2
/app/code/Vendor/Test/Plugin/Shipping.php</b> on line <b>103</b>
```

Comment: Did you try to clear var/generation ?

Comment: Yes already did @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

class Shipping
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'Shipping';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $_result;

    /**
     * @var RateCollectorInterface
     */
    protected $_rateCollector;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        RateCollectorInterface $rateCollector,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->_rateCollector = $rateCollector;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject
     * @param $collectRatesResult
     * @return RateCollectorInterface
     */
    public function afterCollectRates(
        $subject,
        $collectRatesResult
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $collectRatesResult->getResult();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('shipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle('Title');
        $method->setMethod('shipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle('Method Title');

        $amount = 100;
        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $collectRatesResult;
    }
}
```

Result on cart page:

[image: Result on cart page]

Both parameters: `$subject` and `$collectRatesResult` are instances of the `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping` class. There is no need to create a new result object using factory, because it already exists inside the `$collectRatesResult` object:

[image: debug]

You should just add your method to the existing result.

**NOTE:** important thing is you need to have the normal carrier with code you are using in the `$method->setCarrier('shipping');` (in the example the code is `shipping`)

Comment: @PayalPatel I was glad to help :)

Comment: @PayalPatel Please, check new note at the end of the answer. It is important to have a normal carrier to make it work.

Comment: Ok, I got it @SiarheyUchukhlebau

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your method like this:

```
public function afterCollectRates(
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
    RateRequest $request
) {
    //your code here.
}
```

Comment: I already did @Marius, When i put 2 arguments in `afterCollectRates` method i got error `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed`

Answer (score 0):

For creating an After plugin you will need to pass 2 parameter.

So in your case for the method `afterCollectRates`it should take to 2 parameters:

```
public function afterCollectRates(
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
) {
    //your code here.
}
```

Here:

- `$subject` is the object of the \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping class through which you can access public properties/methods of the class
- `$request` is the instance returned by the \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectRates()

And always remember to flush the magento cache whenever creating or modifying Plugins (Interceptors)

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

> [Devdoc Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods)